# function not found when calling a function from namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

I have an R package with bunch of functions (all are exported). One of the function calls another function internally while running. But when I run this function via namespace without loading the entire package, it throws an error: 'could not find function ..'

For e.g:
`foo` and `bar` are two functions. `foo` calls `bar` internally. But when I call `foo` via namespace i.e, `mypackage::foo()` it throws an error `could not find function "bar"`. If I load the library first and run via namespace it runs properly.

```
#doesnot work
mypackage::foo()
could not find function "bar"
#works
library(mypackage)
mypackage::foo()
```

I have exported both function and both are present in NAMESPACE file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the `::` or `:::` fuc[nctions is that only the function code is pulled into the workspace. So none of ancillary or supporting functions in that `mypackage` are pulled into the "interpreter space", i.e. the objects that the interpreter can see. So you option 2 "works" and your option 1 fails. For what seem to me to be obvious reasons.

When I am hacking a function that I know is derived from a *loaded* a namespace, I generally finish the hacking process with:

```
 environment(hacked_fun) <- environment(orig_fun)
```

But that's not an option when you pull code from disk with the "mult-colon-functions". This is also a major reason why experienced R programmmers do their development in packages.The coding discipline of making a package also supports defining package dependencies.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this ? Or only way is to make this `bar` function as an internal function by not exporting it ?

Comment: You could always look at the code of the function and edit a copy to use a mypackage:::other_func call for any dependency.